# batch function with two parameters, returning one

Tags: windows, function, batch-file, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to write a batch function that receives a parameter and returns a parameter without altering the input parameter. I've tried this:

```
set "argument2=bleepblorp"
echo second argument is %argument2%
call :bloop %argument1%, %argument2%
echo BACK FROM LOOP
echo argument one is %argument1%
pause
:end

:bloop
echo IN BLOOP
echo second argument is %2
set input=%2
set %1=%input%
:eof
```

When it runs, inside the function %1 is empty, and %2 returns empty. I also tried passing the input through parameter 1 and returning through parameter 2, like so:

```
set "argument1=bleepblorp"
echo first argument is %argument1%
call :bloop %argument1%, %argument2%
echo BACK FROM LOOP
echo argument two is %argument2%
pause
:end

:bloop
echo IN BLOOP
echo first argument is %1
set input=%1
set %2=%input%
:eof
```

Now %1 contains the input data, and %input% is successfully set to %1, but setting %2 to %input% gets a "The syntax of this command is incorrect" error. I was trying to follow the pattern [explained here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_functions_with_return_values.htm) although obviously that example passes no data into the function.

I'm probably making some totally noob mistake, so I apologize, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "empty parameter" is a concept that doesn't exist in `cmd`. Both your snippets pass only one parameter to the subroutine (function)

Comment: (referring to your first snippet) I guess the second parameter should be the variable name that gets defined in the subroutine. change to `call :bloop %argument1%, argument2` (the second parameter should be  not a variable, but a variable *name*)

Comment: @Stephan EDIT: Hadn't read second comment yet. See below.

  ||  In the first snippet, I tried setting argument2 to a value. It still doesn't return the value of %input%. How do I pass a value back out of the function?

Comment: @Stephan Sorry, didn't read your second comment. That seems to have worked, thank you!